# Normal Mapping problems

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've followed many online tutorials for normal mapping, and have gotten it working, to a degree...

I cannot seem to make it work properly unless the polygon is perpendicular to the view vector.

I have created a video to illustrate this, as pictures are not really sufficient to show what I mean.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D4o_zy-61s

I have posted my shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 400
layout (location = 0) in vec3 attribPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 attribNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 attribTexCoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 attribTangent;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 attribBinormal;

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 mvm;
uniform mat3 nm;
uniform vec3 lightPos_World;

out vec2 vUvs;
out vec3 lightPos_Eye;
out vec3 vertexPos_Eye;
out vec3 normalDir_Eye;
out vec3 normalDir_World;
out mat3 tbnMatrix;

void main()
{
    vUvs = attribTexCoord;
    normalDir_World = attribNormal;
    normalDir_Eye = (nm * attribNormal);
    vec3 t = nm * attribTangent;
    vec3 n = nm * attribNormal;
    vec3 b = nm * cross(n,t);

    mat3 tbnMatrix = mat3(t.x, b.x, n.x,
                          t.y, b.y, n.y,
                          t.z, b.z, n.z);

    vertexPos_Eye = (mvm * vec4(attribPosition,1.0)).xyz;
    lightPos_Eye = (mvm * vec4(lightPos_World,1.0)).xyz;

    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(attribPosition,1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 400
layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 frag_main;
struct PointLight{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
    float intensity;
};

uniform PointLight light[2];
uniform sampler2D colorTexture;
uniform sampler2D normalTexture;
uniform mat4 mvm;
//  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//  FLAGS - all flags start false;
//  [0][0] = colour map
//  [0][1] = normal map
//  [0][2] = unused
//  [0][3] = show normal map in colour channel
//  [1][0] = use tangent space
//  [1][1] = unused
//  [1][2] = unused
//  [1][3] = unused
//  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
uniform bvec4 flags[2];

in vec3 vertexPos_Eye;
in vec3 normalDir_World;
in vec3 normalDir_Eye;
in vec2 vUvs;
in mat3 tbnMatrix;


void main(){

    uint numLights=2;

    vec3 colorFragment;
    if(flags[0][0]){
        colorFragment = texture(colorTexture,vUvs).xyz; 
    }else{
        colorFragment = vec3(0.5);  
    }

    vec3 normalMapNormal = (texture(normalTexture,vUvs).rgb * 2) - 1;
    vec3 normalDir;
    if(flags[0][1]){
        normalDir = normalize(normalDir_Eye);
    }else{
        normalDir =  normalize(normalMapNormal.rgb);
    }

    vec4 outColor = vec4(1);
    outColor.xyz = vec3(0);

    float duller = 1/numLights;
    for(int i = 0;i< numLights;i++){
        vec3 lightPos_Eye = (mvm * vec4(light[i].position,1.0)).xyz;
        vec3 lightDir_Eye = normalize(lightPos_Eye - vertexPos_Eye);
        vec3 lightDir_Tangent = lightDir_Eye * tbnMatrix;

        vec3 vertDir_Eye = normalize(-vertexPos_Eye);
        vec3 vertDir_Tangent = vertDir_Eye * tbnMatrix;

        vec3 halfDir_Eye = normalize(vertDir_Eye + lightDir_Eye);
        vec3 halfDir_Tangent = halfDir_Eye * tbnMatrix;

        vec3 Ia = colorFragment.xyz * light[i].ambient;
        vec3 Id;
        vec3 Is;

        // tangent space
        Id = (colorFragment.xyz * light[i].diffuse ) * max(dot(lightDir_Tangent, normalDir), 0);
        Is = light[i].specular * pow(max(dot(halfDir_Eye, normalDir), 0), light[i].shininess*2);
        // eye space
        //Id = (colorFragment.xyz * light[i].diffuse ) * max(dot(lightDir_Eye, normalDir), 0);
        //Is = light[i].specular * pow(max(dot(halfDir_Eye, normalDir), 0), light[i].shininess*2);

        outColor.xyz += (Ia + Id + Is);

    }

    if(flags[0][3]){
        outColor.xyz = normalDir;
    }
    frag_main = (outColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the line:

```
vec3 b = nm * cross(n,t);
```

but it should be:

```
vec3 b = cross(n,t);
```

there is no need to multiply by `nm` again, since `n` and `t` are in desired camera space.

Another thing:

```
lightPos_Eye = (mvm * vec4(lightPos_World,1.0)).xyz;
```

Since `lightPos_World` is in world space (as name suggests), you should multiply it by something like *world_matrix*, not by *model view*. Or just compute `lightPos_Eye` in the application code and send it to the vertex shader.

It is quite hard to manage all those different vectors and having them in one proper space. Sometimes visual bugs are quite delicate and hard to spot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately it's still the same after I make that change.

Comment: I've added one more thing I've noticed - maybe wrong light pos calculation. Hope it helps

Comment: I also tried changing that. With that change, the lights stay relative to the camera, and multiplying it by the modelview matrix, (which I'm taking only from the camera rotation) was a fix to keep the lights "stationary" relative to camera movement.

It doesn't solve the problem of needing to be perpendicular to the polygon though unfortunately.

I didn't think to try that though, so thanks!